# Connection drop from postgresql on azure virtual machine

Tags: database, postgresql, azure, ubuntu

I am a bit new to postgresql db. I have done a setup over Azure Cloud for my PostgreSQL DB.

It's Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (4vCPU, 8GB RAM) machine with PostgreSQL 9.6 version.

The problem that occurs is when the connection to the PostgreSQL DB stays idle for some time let's say 2 to 10 minutes then the connection to the db does not respond such that it doesn't fulfill the request and keep processing the query.

Same goes with my JAVA Spring-boot Application. The connection doesn't respond and the query keep processing.

This happens randomly such that the timing is not traceable sometimes it happens in 2 minutes, sometimes in 10 minutes & sometimes don't.

I have tried with PostgreSQL Configuration file parameters. I have tried:

tcp_keepalive_idle, tcp_keepalive_interval, tcp_keepalive_count.

Also statement_timeout & session_timeout parameters but it doesn't change anyway.

Any suggestion or help would be appreciable.

Thank You

Comment: Did this get resolved? You can investigate the issue with PostgreSQL server logs: Server logs in Azure Database for PostgreSQL - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-server-logs

Comment: I am not using Azure Database for PostgreSQL service. I am running PostgreSQL in virtual machine. & I have seen the logs there is just one line as "could not receive data from client: Connection timed out" that's it, nothing else is there.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem, we are experiencing exactly the same problem, we left not stoned unturned in finding the root cause ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting up PostgreSQL DB  connection on Azure VM you have to be aware that there are Unbound and Outbound connections timeouts . According to 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections#idletimeout ,Outbound connections have a 4-minute idle timeout. This timeout is not adjustable. For inbound timeou  there is an option to change in on Azure Portal.

We run into similar issue and were able to resolve it on client side. We changed Spring-boot  default Hikari configuration as follow:

hikari:

- connection-timeout: 20000
- validation-timeout: 20000
- idle-timeout: 30000
- max-lifetime: 40000
- minimum-idle: 1
- maximum-pool-size: 3
- connection-test-query: SELECT 1
- connection-init-sql: SELECT 1

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I tried these settings and they have improved the situation but did not fully solve the connection issues for me entirely.